# php preg match get only last matched string

Tags: php, curl, preg-match, explode

I need to get last HTTP headers. My string is:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Date: Sat, 30 Apr 2016 09:48:56 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.34
Location: 2.php
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html

HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Date: Sat, 30 Apr 2016 09:48:57 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.34
Location: 3.php
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 30 Apr 2016 09:48:57 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.34
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html
```

But I need to get last headers. I tried to explode this string with **\n\n** but I couldn't get the result. Is it possible to do it with preg_match?

Answer (score 0):

Gotcha!
I need to explode it with this code:

```
explode("\r\n\r\n", $header);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `preg_split` and `array_pop` functions:

```
// $headers is your initial string
$headers_splitted = preg_split("/\R{2}/", $headers);

print_r(array_pop($headers_splitted));
```

The output:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 30 Apr 2016 09:48:57 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.34
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html
```